# Looking for a book on Differential Equations *with solutions*

Tags: calculus, reference-request, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm studying differential equations (specifically Laplace Transforms) right now with my college assigned 'Differential Equations with Application and Historical Notes'-George F Simmons. While I like the text, I'm not a big fan of the fact that there are not many solved examples and a solution manual isn't available.

Can you guys suggest a decent book with a good range of questions (easy as well as difficult) which most importantly, has a solution manual available to refer to, after I've dwelled on a question for hours and still haven't figured it out.

Comment: Schaum's outline?

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.cramster.com/ ?  They have solutions for a lot of text books.

Comment: MIT Video Lectures http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03-differential-equations-spring-2010/video-lectures/

Answer (score 6):

For a text with a [solution manual](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0495826723): See P. Blanchard, R. L. Devaney, G. R. Hall, [Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1133109039), 4th Ed., 2011.

Another, less expensive choice ("cheap" compared to most textbooks), is [Ordinary Differential Equations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486649407), from *Dover Books on Mathematics* collection. The book has received great reviews, and includes solutions to most of the exercises.

For another "cheap" reference, see [Schaum's Outline of Differential Equations, 3Ed](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071611622). The link will take you to Amazon.com where you can "preview" the book, it's table of contents, etc..

---

The following are not "text books" in the usual sense of the term, but

- [Paul's Online Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/DE.aspx) may help elucidate some of the concepts you're struggling with, and includes many worked examples, with solutions.
- See also [Khan Academy: Differential Equations](http://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations), where you can access tutorials, and accompanying exercises with solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Another book is *Elementary Differential Equations* @ [http://www.amazon.com/Elementary-Differential-Equations-William-Boyce/dp/0470458321/ref=dp_ob_title_bk/177-7352718-7974048](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470458321). It has a student's solution manual and an instructor's solution manual.